# Красивый способ добавить событие на изменение свойства

Tags: c#

Есть класс, содержащий свойство, и событие, которое должно происходить при изменении этого свойства:

```
class A
{
    public Value { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
}
```

Есть два других класса, которые могут это свойство изменять и должны оповещаться, если свойство было изменено не ими. Вернее даже так: оповещаться они могут в любом случае, но должна быть возможность узнать кто именно инициировал изменение.

Проблема в том, что в Value {set; } передаётся лишь новое значение, и узнать инициатора уже не получится. И единственный выход, что я вижу -- это заменить Value {get; set;} на set(newValue, initiator); get();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть ещё DependencyProperty. Вроде бы считается более продвинутым механизмом, чем сущности компонентной модели .NET. Хотя тоже не совсем понятно, чем это могло бы помочь.

Я бы сделал свойство только для чтения, а менял бы его значение через метод с двумя параметрами. А перед этим я бы подумал, насколько правильно спроектировано приложение. Знание о том, кто изменил свойство объекта, инициировавшего событие, противоречит идее событий как таковых. Может, Вам просто не бросать событие об изменении свойства, если фактически значение не поменялось?

Answer (score 7):

В C# уже есть механизм для подобного рода оповещений - [**INotifyPropertyChanged.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

*Пример взаимодействия такого класса и уведомления всех подписчиков при изменения какого-либо свойства объекта:*

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string imageFullPath;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string ImageFullPath
    {
        get { return imageFullPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value != imageFullPath)
            {
                imageFullPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageFullPath");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

Также вполне возможно выполнять отдельную обработку для каких-либо конкретных свойств *(`ImageFullPath` в случае этого примера):*

```
protected void OnImageFullPathChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = ImageFullPathChanged;

    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}

public event EventHandler ImageFullPathChanged;
```

Comment: Видимо я не совсем точно описал задачу.
Допустим Маша реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged и обладает свойством Замужем. Также у нас есть тайно влюблённый в неё Петя, который подписан на изменения свойств Маши. И если кто-то возьмёт Машу замужу, Петя узнает об этом и, поняв что жизнь кончена, тут же застрелится.
А теперь представим, что Пете повезло и Маша вышла замуж за него. Тут к нему приходит событие и бам, кровь, паника, дикий ужас на лицах гостей.
В общем, я не понимаю, как с помощью INotifyPropertyChanged Петя мог бы узнать, что это именно он муж Маши.

Comment: Если Петя сам берёт Машу за руку, он об этом знает постольку поскольку он сам вызывает сеттер свойства.

Comment: @Jofsey в утверждении "если кто-то возьмёт Машу замуж" не содержится условия, что это не может быть сам Петя, поэтому все правильно, он по условию обязан застрелиться в загсе =) не забывайте что машина не думает, а только исполняет, поэтому любое утверждение должно быть максимально полным, соотетственно при получении подобного сообщения, чтобы не случилось беды. нужно дополнительно проверять, что статус самого Пети не поменялся.

Answer (score 2):

Первый способ Вы сами описали - это действительно сделать изменение свойства через метод с двумя параметрами.

Более "замороченный" способ - добавьте в событие параметр объект-инициатор, и при вызове события из сеттера пробегитесь вверх по стеку и с помощью Reflection определите класс, из которого выполняется вызов. Не знаю, то ли это, что Вам нужно, но я в некоторых местах использовал подобный подход. Плох он, в первую очередь, непредсказуемым поведением при вызове из лямбд и прочих анонимных вещей.

Добиться чуть лучшего поведения можно путем установки на потенциальных инициаторов изменений  (классы или методы) дополнительных атрибутов и искать по стеку класс (или метод - в зависимости от того что нужно), который выполняет вызов.

P.S. про чтение стека вызовов можно почитать [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx).

Comment: Не только лямбд. Вообще, код будет по-разному себя вести в Debug и Release из-за inlining.